# Style internal links based on the tags of the linked post

Tags: css, links

When I internally link to one post in the body of another, I’d like the link to be styled based on the tags that the linked post belongs to.

For example, say I have tags “good” and “bad”. When I link to a post that’s tagged “good”, I want the link to be highlighted in green. When I link a post tagged “bad”, I want the link highlighted in red. I want to do this *without* having to check the tags of every post I link to and manually add a css class to the link each time in order to style it. If I change the tags of a post, I'd like any internal links to that post to update their style to match.

Is there any way to retrieve the tags of a linked post at some point when the linking page is loading, in order to add a css class or otherwise alter the style of the displayed link?